# AS3 sending and receiving OSC messages

Tags: actionscript-3, udp, osc

Has anyone successfully sent and received an OSC msg from the same application? I am using the as3/tuio lib: http://bubblebird.at/tuioflash/guides/sending-osc/ and it seems to get a litte messy when you try to go both ways...

I am receiving right now...and based on a series of comparisons, need to ping another system with an osc msg. I am building this on a mac right now.

Comment: what does "get a little messy" mean?  specifically what is the problem you're seeing?  do you have any code you can post?

Comment: I have since figured it out. It was a general question to see if anyone has successfully sent and received OSC messages within the same app. Turns out, a mac has compatibility issues with the DatagramSocket and thusly cannot go in and out. However everything I built runs fine on a PC.